# Jquery ready method and load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access the DOM inside the ready() method. I know that the ready() function runs after the DOM is loaded, well in my case when I am trying to access an element, the Jquery returns undefined.

I tried then to nest the ready() function and the $(window).on("load", function()) and still when I try to access the  element sometimes it returns undefined. Sometimes it returns what I expect which is an order id but other times it randomly returns undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    var order_id = $("section.orderConfirmation-section").find("strong").html();
    console.log("order id: ", order_id)
  });
});
```

When I console log the order id sometimes it returns a number "3123" which is the order id, but other times it returns undefined. I don't understand why this happens because I am attempting to access the DOM, after the entire window is loaded. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `window.load` fires before `document.ready`, so nesting the former within the latter is redundant. The only way I can see the behaviour you describe occurring is if the elements are loaded dynamically - via AJAX for example. If that's the case, use a callback

Comment: Do you have any other javascript running?  e.g. something that sets the content after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: No, what the entire script does is it gets the order id from the DOM and then sends the data to a third party (Segment), it is an order confirmation page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you may be right. The website uses a BigCommerce theme so the content of the page is rendered using handlebars. I tried to use a timeout function and it works but then I wanted to use a different approach and for some reason using JQuery seemed the solution.

Answer (score -1):

What is this `section.orderConfirmation-section` I don't think so this is HTML tag I think this is class or id, so please use `.` or `#` for track this attribute and also you don't need to use the window on load inside the ready function.

Thanks

```
<section>
<div class="orderConfirmation-section">
   <strong>23</strong> <!-- i want to select this div-->
</div>
</section>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var order_id = $("section .orderConfirmation-section").find("strong").html();
    console.log("order id: ", order_id);
});
```

I get id like this.

Comment: `<section>` is an HTML tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) and `$("section.orderConfirmation-section")` will access to every section element with orderConfirmation-section class as well as `$("div.orderConfirmation-section")` will get the `<div>` you defined

Comment: @VirgilioGM `<section>` defined, please use above code I hope it's worked for you.

Comment: If there is no div and it is the section element that has the orderConfirmation-section class and contains the strong element, you would have the same structure that (I think) the OP has and you could use the same code that he used to access the element (`$("section.orderConfirmation-section")`). IMHO your answer should not refer to section.orderConfirmation-section is not an HTML tag because it is a valid JQuery selector to access the section element with the class orderConfirmation-section.

Comment: @VirgilioGM I am not getting your point please send me your HTML code then let you know how to get a value which inside `<strong>` tag.
Thanks

Comment: With this HTML `<section class="orderConfirmation-section"><strong>23</strong></section>` you can access to the `strong` content as the OP said in the question: `$("section.orderConfirmation-section").find("strong").html()` so this part of the original code is correct.

Comment: okay, then you get your Id like this. you don't need to make a space between section and `.orderConfirmation-section` you can do like this .. `$(document).ready(function() {
    var order_id = $("section.orderConfirmation-section").find("strong").html();
    console.log("order id: ", order_id);
});`

Comment: please check there it's working for me. 
Thanks  
https://jsfiddle.net/sanat/cutf5zn2/2/